# How do i use codeanywhere snippets

Tags: code-snippets, codeanywhere

How do i use code anywhere snippets? I have entered a snippets but i am not sure how the "name" or tab "trigger" is used. I have entered "parseget" as name, 1 as tab trigger (because I was not sure how it was used).

I have searched the web and read the very short doc on codeanywhere. I have also have even put in a support ticket with no reply (maybe because I have a free account).

Is anyone familiar with using snippets on codeanywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also put in a support request (having had exactly the same issue!) and the docs on snippets have now been updated- see http://docs.codeanywhere.com/preferences/snippets.html

Answer (score 1):

updating link as the above is now 404.

https://docs.codeanywhere.com/#snippets

doesnt really explain it though, the tabtrigger input box defines the snippet you want to use, for example if you enter `newclass` and then just type `newclass` in your file and press enter you will get your snippet.

does seem to support tabbing though variable names though unfortunately.

also doesnt matter if you have a free account or paid account, CA are the worst at replying to tickets or even acknowledging you exist. took me 2 months to get a reply to a ticket once and it wasnt even a solution.